# Hello I am new to prisma. I am migrating from mongoose. How can I make my model VerificationToken so the expires at filed will have now + 10 minutes?

Tags: database, mongoose, next.js, prisma

How can I hide the password field in prisma like select false in mongoose and how can I create a VerificationFiled model so it will automatically generated expires at field having new Date() + 10 minutes,

I am expecting developers to help me. I am stuck in prisma orm and migrating from mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit or unselect fields in mongo with

```
this.userModel.find({_id "SOME_ID"}).projection({password: 0})

// Aggregate way
this.userModel.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: "SOME_ID"}},
  {$project: {password: 1}}
])
```

Comment: No I want this feature in prisma not in mongoose